# Delphi XE Form and Source in dual monitor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, multiple-monitors

Somoene knows if i can setup my IDE for display source code in one monitor and frm in another? I talk about the same .pas because 2 different .pas i can view in each monitor.

Comment: good old delphi 6 does this very nicely!

Comment: Any version before Delphi 2005 (or maybe 8, which should have introduced the "Galileo" IDE) has no issue with multiple monitors. It's only when they decided Delphi should have aped VS they switched to an embedded designed by default (which also has more limitations, i.e. the menu bar does not work in the embedded designed, it does in the floating one...). It happens when a company is no longer able to think on its own, but blindly follow the stream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about XE, but in 2007 you can go to `Tools->Options` to bring up the options dialog, then uncheck `"Embedded Designer"` under `VCL Designer`.

After restarting the IDE, the form design will be in an undocked (and undockable) window. The code editor will then be detached from the form, so can be moved to another monitor.

**However:**
If you move the form around, the forms default position (Left and top) will change, and may move off the default monitor if you use `Form.Position := poDesigned`. That's the main reason **I** prefer the embedded designer.

**Edit**

Note as well that all of the docked windows (object inspector, watches, project manager etc) can easily be undocked as well, then docked again.

Comment: The option was removed from XE4 - XE8 and you had to use a registry hack.
Apparently they added it back in 10.
For the registry hack - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647635/how-can-i-disable-the-embedded-designer-in-xe6

Answer (score 6):

You can open multiple edit views of the same module (right-click in source code editor, select "New Edit Window" from the context menu).

Comment: Then use View > New Edit Window to detach one of the duplicate edit views from the docked IDE, you can then drag it to the second display... it's what I do.

Comment: @LaKraven - I don't know about XE (and 2009,2010), but 2006/2007 only allows one copy of a form (or other container) to be open when using the embedded designer. `New Edit Window` moves a form into a new embedded designer, but removes from its current designer.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the source code (.pas) on one monitor and the visual designer (form) in another, use the Desktop Speedsetting in the IDE's toolbar, and set it to "Classic Undocked". Arrange the IDE the way you like between monitors, and then click the "Save Desktop" button next to the SpeedSetting dropdown. Name the layout you like, and then save it as your default desktop. Also see @ldsandon's comment about needing to uncheck the embedded designer in the IDE's options dialog as well.

I personally prefer the newer embedded designer layout (the default), and put the IDE on the secondary monitor with the application running in the primary one. You can then step through code in the debugger and view the output on the primary monitor at the same time.

Comment: Thank's bro, but i wanna the Frm (design) in one monitor and source code, of the same .pas. Even in non docked ide style, this feature can't be set.

Comment: That's not enough. You have to enable the floating form designer in Options to be able to move the forms being designed to a different monitor. Because Delphi allows for a debug configuration, it is very easy to have an undocked configuration while designing the application, and switch to a docked one while debugging. Unluckily the floating designed is not an option that can be switched with desktops, it's an application wide one.