# Form/Unit switching in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi

How do I get a projects form, as well as its unit, shown both on the tabs/pages?
Currently I have to use "Toggle form/unit" or press F12

Just out of curiosity's sake, doesn't really bother me, but would be nice to know (I switched over from Delphi 7, so I must still get used to stuff)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch using Code/Design Tabs in the bottom.

Comment: Ahh ok, didn't even see it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe in XE you can alter the display to display as it did in Delphi 7.

Here is a link describing it. I have not watched it as I don't have much time but being from embaracadero I am going out on a limb and saying it will help.

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/andreanolanusse/how-to-configure-delphi-2010-to-look-work-and-feel-like-delphi-7/

Comment: That would be useful, any Ideas how?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643081/delphi-xe-form-and-source-in-dual-monitor